# QuickFIX rejects ExecutionReport due to missing Symbol field

Tags: quickfix

I have a FIX client written in nQuickfix.net which is connected to a FIX server.
I send a NewOrderSingle and it sends me an ExecutionReport message.
But the message is not passed to the application layer, it is rejected in the QuickFIX layer.
When I check the log files, it says Required field missing(55). 55 means Symbol field which is not a required field in Execution Report. So, why does it reject the ExecReport?

Comment: Which version of FIX protocol are you implementing?

Comment: @stexcec, it is 4.4 at both sides.

Comment: Symbol appears in multiple sub-groups within the message.  For instance, if the message includes group 711 then the symbol *is* required within that group (because it's the first field in each group element).

Comment: It's hard to give an exact diagnosis without seeing the full message.

Comment: 8=FIX.4.4|9=128|35=D|34=63|49=MOBY|52=20140331-13:48:24.778|56=MYFX|1=17006|11=2|38=2|40=1|44=1.37848|54=1|55=EURUSD|60=20140331-16:48:24.778|10=140|  
8=FIX.4.4|9=127|35=8|34=1532|49=MYFX|52=20140331-13:48:25.903|56=MOBY|6=1.37848|11=2|14=2|17=4623798|37=1|39=2|40=1|54=1|150=F|151=0|9044=15|10=057|  
8=FIX.4.4|9=105|35=3|34=64|49=MOBY|52=20140331-13:48:24.935|56=MYFX|45=1532|58=Required tag missing|371=55|372=8|373=1|10=111|

Comment: actually, the client does not try to read the Symbol field. Why does the engine rejects then?

Comment: Which version of QF/n are you using?